# How can I align right and left of 2 divs

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/) to create a sample page, the problem is that I can't get 2 divs to alaign by the left and right padding, in a sort of way I want to expand the second div, to exactly match the first.

[image]

I have 2 divs, 1 containing an image:

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="maskbanner">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.maskbanner{
     background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1031x302') no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 0;
     padding-top: 30%;
}
```

and after that I have a div containing a row and a col:

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    .. elements ..
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the class:

```
.row .col {
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 .75rem;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

adds .75 em to the left and right of the column, I tried to give that "extra" padding to my first div trying to match that padding, but it doesn't seem to work, I also want to keep that align responsive.

Here is my project:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxQBQY)

Comment: After I saw your codePen I didn't clearly know what you want at your project. In your DEMO I saw all container element align center but the title div, you want title center too??

Comment: I want the right and left padding to align in both divs, you can check out my image for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to structure your html, css according to their rule. Inside `container` should have `row` and inside `row` should have `col`. So all the element inside will have the same padding, margin and it will align correctly.

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="maskbanner">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In case you don't want to do that, create another css class like

```
.row.custom-row { 
   margin-left: -0.75rem;
   margin-right: -0.75rem;
}
```

and add it to the row of 2nd div

```
<div class="section">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row custom-row">
    .. elements ..
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```